# Connect through SSH tunnel on Logstash - Elastic cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-jdbc, elastic-cloud

I try to connect to my MySQL server with logstash on our elastic cloud cluster, the problem is that we use SSH tunnel on the sql server. Is there a way, using the logstash pipeline creation interface on elastic cloud, to connect to a mysql server using SSH tunnel ?

Interface is as follow, there is not that much parameters..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, I'm afraid that's not part of the JDBC input plugin of Logstash (which will do the connection to MySQL). Can you set up the SSH tunnel between your Logstash server and MySQL manually?